# Hiding non-user accounts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have multiple accounts on my Windows 7 system. Sevral of these are for services, rather than users, yet they still show on the Windows 7 Login screen.

Is it possible NOT to display these non-user accounts on the login screen?

Comment: Use any Windows 7 tweaker tool -- it should have such option available (Yamicsoft Windows 7 definitely can do this). You can hide such accounts using `secpol.msc` (then "Security Settings | Local Policies | User Rights Assignment | Deny log on locally"), but it is not available for Home Premium. Other than that -- you will have to edit registry directly.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Vista and Windows 7 you can specify certain accounts to be "special accounts" that do not show-up on the logon screen.

Basically it is a list in the registry below the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`

There you can create of each account name an DWORD of value 0 using the account name as the value name.

A detailed description including screen shots can be found here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/remove-user-accounts-from-the-logon-screen-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Be aware that this method disables the account, so you will not be able to “`runas`” the user.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to disagree the account will not be "disabled". It just prevents the user account from being displayed in user account lists. In any "runas" command that allows to enter the user name as a string you can use it.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested and it worked (it didn’t before ಠ_ఠ). That’s good, but unfortunately it definitely prevents it from working in the UAC dialogs. For example, add the admin account to the list, then try running a program as admin from Explorer, it will prompt you with the UAC dialog, but the password field and `[Yes]` buttons will be disabled (unless you have another admin account available and enabled which of course, will show them on the login screen). I suppose you could always go through the command-line, but that’s not good for most purposes. `:-(`